# Inputting variables until a negative number is entered

Tags: c, loops, variables, input

I'm trying to figure out a homework assignment in C. The instructions state to have the user input integers in a loop until they enter a negative number, and then to output the sum of all the numbers. The second part seems pretty straight forward to me, but I can't wrap my head around the first part. How do you store a user input integer with a loop?

This is all I have so far.

```
int main(void)
{
      int i = -1;
      while(i > -1)
      {
          printf("Please enter a number %i. When finished, enter a negative number.", i);
          scanf("%i", &i);
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(i>-1)` isn't going to do much if `i == -1`

Comment: Well that won't even enter the loop as the condition is false to begin with.

Comment: `int i = -1;` here i is already `-1`. how it enter in while loop ? (you should know `-1` is not greater then `-1`). I think you need `do..while` loop.

Comment: OH duh that makes more sense. But how would I continue to store a value in the same integer multiple times?

Comment: Why do you print the number before it was entered? What happens if the user enters something that is not a valid number? For your loop, the `do ... while` construct might be more suitable. You should also make use of `scanf`s return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0,sum = 0;
    do
    {
       sum +=i;  // use sum here if you don't want to add -ve value
       printf("Please enter a number i. When finished, enter a negative number. ");
       scanf("%i",&i);
       //sum +=i;  // use sum here if you want to add -ve value also to the sum
    }
    while(i > -1);

    printf("Sum = %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have assigned `i = -1` and checking if `i` is greater than `-1` which is false. So, the loop isn't executing. 
You can try this.

```
#include<stdio.h>    
int main()    
{    
    int i=0,sum=0;    
    while(true)    
    {   
        scanf("%d",&i);
        if(i < 0) break;
        sum+=i;    
    }     
    printf("%d\n",sum);     

   return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
int main () {

int number = 0;
int accumulator = 0;
do {
    accumulator += number;
    std::cout << "Enter numbers to accumulate. Use negative number to finish: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> number;
} while (number > 0); //as you can also use -1 as the ending loop

std::cout << accumulator;
return 0;
}
```

**AN EXTRA VERSION FOR C++** and using understandable variable names if someone needs it.